# vi/fugitive: Gpush does not exit... sometimes

Tags: ssh, vi, vim-fugitive

I just started using [fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) in my workflow... very useful! But I've seem to have run into a weird annoyance that I'm hoping someone might have a solution to:

When I run :Gpush, sometimes control never returns to vi. Vi hangs on the output of `git push` until I Ctrl+C to kill "it". I've also tried installing [vim-dispatch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch) and, within [tmux](http://tmux.github.io/), the result is that the `git push` pane never closes. This is even more annoying because I've got to switch down to that pane to Ctrl+C it.

Oddly, if I `ps`, I do not see any git processes running, so I'm not sure what is hanging, exactly... but Ctrl+C does kill "it", whatever "it" is, and control returns to vi.

I've found a [closed github issue](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/issues/531) that mentions similar behavior, but a solution was never posted... it appears the problem eventually just "went away" for the OP, so the issue was closed.

However, a second person replied to the issue some time later saying he was having a similar problem and it seemed to happen when git spawned some kind of "credential cache daemon". I'm not using a credential helper as he is, so that's not my exact issue... but that caused me to notice something else:

I have ssh configured to keep connections open for 5 minutes (`ControlPersist 5m` in my ~/.ssh/config). If I haven't pushed in a while, `git push` causes ssh to spawn a process to persist the connection. This triggers the issue. After 5 minutes, ssh exits, which will fix the problem and cause the tmux pane to close. If I do another push while the connection is still open, it works fine.

So, the problem seems to be when git spawns another process. This obviously doesn't cause any issues when I run git on the command-line, so why does it cause an issue here? And what can I do about it? I don't want to disable the ssh persistent connections because that's useful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who stumbles upon this in the future, I've come up with a solution for my particular case where the ssh process is hanging vim: I disable the ControlPersist option, but only for git commands run inside vim via fugitive by setting the following option in my .vimrc:

```
let g:fugitive_git_executable = "env GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -o ControlPersist=no' git"
```

It's ugly, and I'm sad that I have to disable the persistent connections, but it works.